# adding tow events

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have an form which will send some data to an php file , then return some results as example:

```
<form action"<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" id="data">
  <input type"text" name="first_name"/>
  <input type="text" name="last_name"/>
</form>
```

then in javascript i want catch clcik event in submit form as example :

```
$("#data").submit(function(){
some code .....
});
```

which that will prevent the default action for submitting inputs form to the php file , the question is can i send data of a form for php file and same time catch event for the same form ?

> NOTE the returned data from php file will be needed by another php
>   function

Comment: You need to use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send data to php.

Comment: If your `return data` is needed by another `php function`, why dont you just call that php function at the first place, before sending the data as ajax return, and return the `final output` if any from second php function, as ajax response.

Comment: @Joy , in case i want show the result by jquery i can just catch the returned data via callback function in jquery and show that result , but i was thinking to show the result by php in the same page i think that would be better performance and faster , is that right  ?

Comment: After you load a page, You cant load any data in that same page using php only, without refreshing the page(A New request). To do that you have to use `AJAX`, after you get the `data` in jQuery as a result of a `ajax request`, you can just show the `message/result` to user using jQuery. As you got that data from `php` already, showing that using jQuery/JS wont take much time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent the default behavior of form submit(Which is Page reload) you need to use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) like this

```
$("#data").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //some code .....
});
```

And to post the form data into `php` without refreshing page you need to use any of the jQuery's available `ajax` methods like [`.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) (Which will send form values using `HTTP POST` Method) like

```
$("#data").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();// prevent page reload
    // Now post the form using Ajax
    // $(this).serialize() will return an array of all form fields as
    //                                                 name value pair 
    $.post('some_script.php',$(this).serialize(),function(data){
        // Just to check if everything is working well
        console.log('Form Submitted Successfully.');
        // do whatever you want with the data
   });
});
```

If your php script returns the data in `json` format the you can either set the `content-Type` header using php or force jQuery to treat the return data as `JSON` by specifying the `dataType` as `JSON` in the 4th parameter like

```
   $.post('some_script.php',$(this).serialize(),function(data){
        // Just to check if everything is working well
        console.log('Form Submitted Successfully.');
        // do whatever you want with the data
   },'json');
```

Comment: in case no need to process the returned data from php file and handle the data by javascript that's would be the correct solution , in my case i need to check and process the returned data by php again !

Comment: @moata_u, I just added that `console.log` for quick example, You can do what ever you want with returned data in that success callback.

Comment: ok , you mean can i pass the returned data again to an php file , by using $.post(url,data,callback) again , after success of first post !

Comment: You can process the returned data using JS, but if your `processing` requires something that can't be done with `JS/jQuery` then you can `post` again inside that success callback. But that's not necessary and pointless. As you just returned that data from a `php script`, why dont you just process the data before sending it as return of ajax call?

Comment: i will send the inputs of form to the same page then i will check which input is empty or not, so then i will call php function with these values to create mysql query (this is an search filtering project) , so i need to do it in this way . whatever your answer was helpful .

Comment: It better to use `JS validation` to check if input is empty or not. There are plenty of Validation plugins available like http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation So rather than validating input by php through ajax, I would Suggest you validate using JS.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#data").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.post("<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>",$(this).serialize(),function(r){ //Do Some Action });
});
```

Comment: They'll also probably want to use `$(this).serialize()` to get all of the inputs from the form, rather than listing them individually.

Comment: @Mohit Bumb , in this case the return data from php file will be returned to the callback function in javascript and cant use it again in any php function , i need to process the returned data again by php code.